# rsync exclude not excluding directory

Tags: centos, rsync

I am having issues excluding a single directory from copying from remote machine to my local.

This is the command  I used:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats --exclude='/var/www/html/px3' root@IPHERE:/var/www/html /Users/mainuser/Documents/somefolder
```

folder `/var/www/html/px3` is supposed to be left alone, but the command starts to index its contents. The folder is 100GB big, so I just cancel the command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rsync `exclude` path is relative to the source path.
So in your case you are trying to exclude: `/var/www/html/var/www/html/px3`

You should change it for:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats --exclude=/px3 root@IPHERE:/var/www/html /Users/mainuser/Documents/somefolder
```